# C++ - variadic functions and cout

Tags: c++, logging, io

I have a logging function which accepts variadic parameters. This works fine for say android logging and printf, but I want to do the same with std::cout and file streams. Is there an easy way solve this?

```
void LogManagerImpl::LogInfo(const char* msg, ...)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, msg);

        /* Log to stdout */
        if (mLogToStdOut)
        {
            #ifdef ANDROID
                __android_log_vprint(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, __ENGINE_LOG_TAG, msg, argptr);
            #elif defined _WIN32 || _WIN64
                //printf ("%s:%s",__ENGINE_LOG_TAG,"INFO:"); vprintf(msg, argptr); printf("\n");
                // how do I do the same as above except with for example std::cout?
            #endif
        }

        /* Log to file */
        if (mLogToFile)
        {
                      // TODO

        }

        va_end(argptr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to use a variadic wrapper for C++ streams, just use the corresponding C API such as `vprintf`/`vnsprintf`. Wrapping streams in this way just throws away all the benefits and causes additional complexity.

Why not have your wrapper API use streams, and map them to `printf` on Android platforms. That way you get all the benefits of streams and only lose them on platforms that don't natively support them.

Comment: But then I face the same problem but the other way around; how does one take all the '<<' input and properly format it for Android, a la printf()?

Comment: Just use a stream library using stdio functions inder the hood? A simple version of IOstreams using a locale replacement isn't really much of a problem.